# what is the gradle property android.sdk.channel used for?

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-properties, gradle-managed-device

I have seen references to the gradle property "android.sdk.channel" like here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/206963797 and https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/10/whats-new-in-scalable-automated-testing.html

What exactly is this used for or what are the possible values and/or what they mean?